# Sql procedure for years?

Tags: sql-server

In Sql Server, I wrote a procedure for getting last 3 years, which includes this year, and it returns only year [ like 2011,2010,2009]. This is my procedure. Is there any optimisation required? Please check the procedure.

```
       create procedure UPS_GetYears
      as
       begin
        declare @date varchar(10)
        declare @i int=0
        declare @var varchar(60)
        declare @y int =-1
        select @date = SUBSTRING (CONVERT (varchar,GETDATE(),103),7,4)         
        create table #Temp (years varchar(10))
        while (@i < 3)
        begin           
         insert into #Temp (years) values(@date )           
         select @date = SUBSTRING (convert(varchar, DATEADD (yyyy,@y,getdate()),103),7,4)
         set @i=@i+1
         set @y =@y-1        
        end    
      select * from #Temp 
     end
```

Comment: ya it return only years, actually it is executed successfully, but i am checking the best and simple query for this. Mr. marc_S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just do

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) - N AS years
FROM   (VALUES(0),
              (1),
              (2)) T(N)
```

Also why is this a procedure rather than a TVF?

Comment: Martin Smith your code is simply superb, whta is this TVF, can you explanin me or any reference. i mean what is this TVF

Comment: @Suryasasidhar - TVF is "Table Valued Function". Although as this isn't parameterised at all you could also put it into a view. Then you just `SELECT` from it and it is easier to consume the output in secondary stored procedures than from a stored proc (where you would need to insert the stored proc result into a table first)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an efficient way to do it with a recursive CTE instead of a temp table & loop;

```
declare @start_year int = year(getdate())
;with years(year) as
(
    select @start_year as year
        union all
    select year - 1
        from years
        where year > (@start_year - 2)
)
select * from years
```

Comment: Thank you for reply Alex, i will try and intimate you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - if you want `Years` - why return a `VARCHAR(10)` and not an `INT` ??

When returning an INT, you could make this much easier:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPS_GetYears
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @currYear INT = YEAR(GETDATE())

    DECLARE @Years TABLE(YearValue INT)

    INSERT INTO @Years VALUES(@CurrYear), (@currYear -1), (@currYear -2)

    SELECT * FROM @Years
END
```

Run this and it'lll return `2011, 2010, 2009` as `INT`

Comment: ya nice explanation Mr. marc_s

Answer (score 0):

Why go in for loop. Try not to use while or recursive CTE's as these are not efficient. Try the below code -

```
select * into abc
from
(
select top 3 year(getdate()) - row_number() over (order by (select 1))+1 as myyear
  from sys.all_objects
 ) as qwe

 select * from abc
```